# Angular - 2 :Getting Different Value in html and type Script

Tags: html, angular, typescript, conditional-statements

I am getting two different values to same variable in html and ts(when i console)

Code

```
 hideAmountModal() {
    var self = this;
    self.home_delivery_charge = self.storeService.fetchHomedeliveryData(self.shopId);
    self.home_delivery_charge.subscribe((res: any) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(self.deliveryData.delivery_charge) > parseInt(res[i].amount)) {
          self.check_delivery_charge = true;
          console.log('Deliverycharge',self.deliveryData.delivery_charge,'result',res[i].amount);
          console.log('deliver charge is greater',self.check_delivery_charge);
        }
        else if (parseInt(self.deliveryData.delivery_charge) < parseInt(res[i].amount)){
            self.check_delivery_charge = false;
            console.log('Deliverycharge',self.deliveryData.delivery_charge,'result',res[i].amount);
            console.log('deliver charge is greater',self.check_delivery_charge);
        }
      }
    })
    self.DeliveryChargeValue = true
    self.selectAmountModal.hide();
  }
```

the corresponding Html

```
 <li *ngFor ="let home_charges of home_charge;let in= index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
                <div [class.dull]="check_delivery_charge">
                     <div *ngIf="home_charges.edited == 0"><input type="text" class="d-charge" value=""></div>
                     <div *ngIf="home_charges.edited == 1"><input type="text" class="d-charge" [(ngModel)]="home_charge[in]['delivery_charge']" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  ></div>
                     <span *ngIf="home_charges.range == 0">&euro; order less than {{home_charges.amount}}&euro;</span>
                     <span *ngIf="home_charges.range == 1">&euro; order above  {{home_charges.amount}}&euro;</span>
                     <!-- <span class="rem" *ngIf="home_charges.edited == 0">(Recommend {{home_charges.delivery_charge | number : '1.1-3'}}&euro;)</span> -->
                     <span class="rem" *ngIf="home_charges.edited == 0">(Recommend {{home_charges.delivery_charge}}&euro;)</span>
                          "Check Delivery Charge : {{check_delivery_charge}}
                </div>
              </li>
```

i have the console and result of html below, What could be the reason,

[image]
[image]

as you can see, in the console its true,true,true,false but in result its all false
(if any information more needed can be provided)

Comment: `check_delivery_charge` is the same variable binding in every sequence of your `*ngFor` loop... so of cause it shows the same value for every entry. You would need to hold an array of the result for each entry to be displayed in the `{{check_delivery_charge}}` binding. Or compute the result while looping.

Comment: Here you are using the same variable for every results you have, so it will obviously get your last value processed which is "false".

If you want to have independent value for each row, you must consider using an array of objects, a map, or even a function.

Comment: @Fussel and andrea06590 : Thanks for the info, let me try it using an array.